# Jquery toggle closest items with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle few items with specific class. What was code issue here?

```js
//show hide items with class Network

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.testCategory').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.Network').toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="testCategory">Network</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">RTT</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Capacity</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Jitter</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses up the DOM. You probably want `nextAll()` instead:

```
$('.testCategory').click(function(){
   $(this).nextAll('.Network').toggle();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.testCategory').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.Network').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="testCategory">Network</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">RTT</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Capacity</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Jitter</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead

> Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$('.testCategory').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.Network').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="testCategory">Network</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">RTT</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Capacity</a>
<a href="#" class="Network none">Jitter</a>
```